# Getting "Unresolved compilation problems" errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When running JUnit tests i am getting "Unresolved compilation problems" errors.
But these are not compilation errors.
Eclipse is not reporting any issues in the "problems" tab.

And this is happening on another Eclipse environment. on a mac.
I think the JUnit is running the tests and it is not finding classes that are in other packages. Some yes, some no.
I tried to add to the "Run Configuration" of the JUnit as projects, folders or jars.
Nothing else.
What can this be?
All the errors under the Unresolved Compilation problems are "cannot resolve type, etc".

On the same project on PC with eclipse, all is ok. Only on a Mac with eclipse.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put Junit code here? Unless we see the code, how we can understand it!!

Comment: can u share the code here ?

Comment: It's a big commercial project so i cannot share the code. But like i said there are no errors shown in "problems" section. Its like junit is running and not finding class files in its "classpath". And on the same project on PC with eclipse, all is ok. So really is strange. Only on a Mac with eclipse.

Comment: Can you check all the necessary jars needed to setup on eclipse on mac? One other issue- try building project again? Is JUnit running fine via command line?

Comment: so are you having eclipse issues? this seems to be a question about eclipse, even though it's not explicit. Edited and added notes about Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

In the end it was eclipse's fault.

I just needed to use the project -> clean all projects option.

Thanks!

Bye